# Postgres Azure: Grants for User Removed

Tags: postgresql, azure

I am the admin of a PostgreSQL 11 DB on Azure.
Some of the users only have access to specific views.
The users were created by:

```
CREATE USER M1234 WITH PASSWORD '1234!';

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO M1234;

GRANT SELECT ON table v_xxx TO M1234;

GRANT SELECT ON table v_yyy TO M1234;
```

For some reason the grant for select on one or all the existing views is removed every so often and the users of course cannot access.
I would really appreciate it if anyone has any insight as to why and how this could happen and if there is a more long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

You grant SELECT on existing tables, but for future tables, you need additional permissions
-- Grant access to future tables ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA a_given_schema GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO read access;

Comment: Thanks for responding. The grants are removed from existing tables. I will edit so its clearer.